# PHP/HTML Form isn't passing ANY information.(web browser doesn't warn about resubmission when reloading)

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working on setting up a cloud hosting service. Currently there are 6 packages. After selecting a package and filling in sign up information it *should* go from `/cloud/www/register/service name here/` to `/cloud/www/register/handler/step-1/`(which it does) and then submit some information for the back-end to process and send to a database.(which it doesn't.) it stops at line 1 at `/cloud/www/register/handler/step-1/` which is below, where the page simply outputs "An error has occured", and when reloading the page or going back, the browser doesn't warn about form resubmission.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){ 
    // .. Information checks before sending to database.. 
}else{
    echo "An error has occured";
}
```

The form line in the package registration page:

```
<form action="/cloud/www/register/handler/step-1" method="post">
```

All input fields use "name" not "id" if that's important.(i tried both ways)
If full code is wanted I will post it.

**[[Pages in question]]**

[/cloud/www/register/service/access/index.php](http://pastebin.com/n83KhnCX)

[/cloud/www/register/handler/step-1/index.php](http://pastebin.com/2KqF2msw)

**[[Pages in reference]]**

[/cloud/style/cloud-header.php](http://pastebin.com/DkdmU7qA)

[/cloud/style/cloud-style.html](http://pastebin.com/YFmu1XSU)

[/cloud/www/navigation-bar.html](http://pastebin.com/fnwrtN41)

[/cloud/style/bootstrap-toolkit.css](http://getbootstrap.com)

> Update: I had a friend of mine look at the code. He doesn't see the
>   issue. He asked me to use var_dump($_POST) on the information return
>   page, but it simply output "array(0){ }"

Comment: Hi, Full code might be useful. Do you have several forms on the same page? Is the submit button before the `</form>` tag?

Comment: No and no @EmmanuelO

Comment: You need to provide more code.

Comment: If the submit button is *not* before `</form>`, then that might be the issue.

Comment: @jmattheis Code provided.

Comment: @GolezTrol the submit button *IS* before the `</form>`

Comment: Just for the record, If you just echo an error text, but no different http status code, the browser will think the request is handled well, and won't resubmit the data. So that part of the behaviour makes sense. Question is, why does it echo. Did you do a redirect somewhere? That would cause the post data to be lost. Depending on the type of redirect, the post data is not posted to the new location.

Comment: There is one redirect caused by the form, which directs to `/cloud/www/register/handler/step-1/` but other than that there is no redirect.

Comment: Update: I had a friend of mine look at the code. He doesn't see the issue. He asked me to use var_dump($_POST) on the information return page, but it simply output "array(0){ }"

Answer (score 0):

instead of "// .. Information checks before sending to database.." try putting :
echo "successfully added"

Comment: Look here: http://pastebin.com/2KqF2msw
There isn't actually that comment.